# How do I export all CA certificates from Apple KeyChain into a single PEM bundle?

Tags: macos, ssl, keychain

Considering that I know that the the system KeyChain contains all needed SSL certificates, I do want to generate a single PEM bundle that I can use with other tools that are not able to communicate with Apple keychain. For example: Python requests library or Oracle Java.

Please note that this is not about a specific certificate, that's a bulk operation that I want to make.

Once I have this bundle I can point environment variables like SSL_CERT_FILE and REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE to its location and use it.

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance... What does this have to do with OpenSSL? The best I can tell it does not appear to be related to programming. Are you asking for a tool or command recommendation?

Comment: @jww it may not be evident but it has because the generated pem file would have to be parsable / loadable by openssl.

Comment: Try [KeyChain Dumper](https://www.google.com/search?q=keychain+dumper+github). I use it for security evaluations and some pen testing client side apps. I usually dump the secrets like stored passwords, but you should be able to extract certificates with it.

Answer (score 5):

### (Final solution implementing fix from comments)

```
# If you might use the bundle for different users this path should be readable by most
#TMP_CERT=/usr/local/shared-ca-bundle.pem
TMP_CERT=$HOME/my-ca-bundle.pem
security find-certificate -a -p /System/Library/Keychains/SystemRootCertificates.keychain > $TMP_CERT
security find-certificate -a -p /Library/Keychains/System.keychain >> $TMP_CERT
## If you have a internal company proxy cert (Root CA usually), append it to the .pem file if it wasn't in the system stores
## This adds the variable to your shell config file
echo 'export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE="$HOME/my-ca-bundle.pem"' >> $HOME/.bash_profile
. $HOME/.bash_profile # this loads the variable to the current shell environment
# run your `pip install whatever` or
# `az upgrade` or `az bicep install`
### the Azure CLI is built with Python and uses it for the plugins they use
```

Python/Requests cares about the SystemRootCertificates coming before the System certificates, while curl doesn't seem to care.

An example of the error you would receive from requests if done in the opposite order.

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)
```

Comment: Your problem is simply having the certificate chain out of order. You need to put the SystemRootCertificates first in the resulting PEM, followed by the System keychain. After doing this, I am able to pass the result to requests successfully. I have even added a self-signed root at the end and run it through an SSL proxy without error.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have a handful of non-system CAs, it's not so hard to export them all manually from the Keychain app.

1. Open the Keychain app from Launchpad -> Other -> Keychain Access.
2. In the left-hand panel, select "System Roots" and "Certificates".
3. In the main panel, click on the first certificate and then scroll all the way down and shift-click on the last certificate to select them all.

[image: Keychain Application with all System Root certificates selected]

4. Right-click on one of the selected certificates and select "Export ### items...".
5. Save the file in a nice directory.
6. In the top of the left "Keychains" panel, select "System".
7. Find any custom root CAs that you want included in the bundle, right-click on them, and export them to the same directory as you did in step 5.
8. Open a terminal and navigate to the nice directory. Concatenate all of them together with `cat Certificates.pem <your custom CA>.pem <your other custom CA>.pem > bundle.pem`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid generating the bundle yourself,  I've just discovered that `openssl` installed via Homebrew will automatically generate a PEM bundle from the System Keychain.

Running `brew install openssl` (or `brew info openssl` if already installed), shows the following Caveat:

```
==> Caveats
A CA file has been bootstrapped using certificates from the system
keychain. To add additional certificates, place .pem files in
  /usr/local/etc/openssl@3/certs

and run
  /usr/local/opt/openssl@3/bin/c_rehash
```

Next to that directory, is `/usr/local/etc/openssl\@3/cert.pem`, which you can directly use for SSL_CERT_FILE and REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE.